# Drools decision table create object

Tags: drools, drools-flow

I want to convert the below rule to decision table,

```
when
  customer:Customer(purchase > 1000)
  person:Person()
then
  person.markValuableCustomer(customer.id); 
end
```

I tried to convert this to decision table but I am not sure how to declare the person object. As you can see in the excel I created a new Condition for it.

I tried in a CONDITION column as `person:Person` but I get some error saying condition has to be entered.

So how to create a object in decision table which has to be used in Action column ?

Please find the excel data just in case if image uploaded is not opening.

```
    RuleTable HelloWorld1   
    CONDITION                                            CONDITION             ACTION

    customer:CustomerInfo   
    customer.purchase > "$param" && customer.valid        person:Person();  person.markValuableCustomer(customer.id)

    Purchase    
    1000
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this trick:

```
    RuleTable HelloWorld1   
    CONDITION                      CONDITION        ACTION

    customer:CustomerInfo          person:Person()
    customer.purchase > "$param"   /*$param*/       person.mark(customer.id)
    Purchase    
    1000                              x
```

You can join the cells of the condition column so that a single 'x' is sufficient.

Comment: @luane : Thanks for your reply. I tried your solution but I am getting the same error. Assuming there are 3 columns and 6 rows, what are cells you want to join ?  5:2 and 6:2 ?

Comment: Join those in the condition column for `Person` where the row for CustomerInfo has values 1000 and below. But htis is optional - you can put an 'x' in each row where you want to have `Person` in the rule.